# Reference request on Min-Max theorem

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the following min-max problem

$$\inf_{x\in M} \sup_{y\in N} F(x,y),$$

where  $F: M\times N\to\mathbb R$ is Lipschitz and $y\mapsto F(x,y)$ is concave for all $x\in M$. **Could we derive $\inf_{x\in M} \sup_{y\in N} F(x,y)=\sup_{y\in N} \inf_{x\in M}F(x,y)$ if $M\subset \mathbb R^m$ and  $N\subset\mathbb R^n$ are both compact?**

PS: To the best of my knowledge, the reference on Min-Max theorem is from M. Sion : https://msp.org/pjm/1958/8-1/pjm-v8-n1-p14-p.pdf However, the convexity of $x\mapsto F(x,y)$ is missing in my case. Any comments or references are highly appreciated!

PS2: Thank Nik Weaver for the counterexample and Iosif Pinelis for providing a helpful condition. The function above is defined as

$$F(x,y)~:=~\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{V_k(x,y)}\left\{|z-x_k|^2-y_k\right\}\rho(z)dx+\sum_{k=1}^n p_ky_k,$$

where $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)\in\Omega^n$, $y=(y_1,\ldots, y_n)\in\mathbb R^n$ and

$$V_k(x,y)~:=~\big\{z\in\Omega:~ |z-x_k|^2-y_k\le |z-x_{i}|^2-y_{i},~ \forall 1\le i\le n\big\}.$$

Here $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^d$ is compact, $\rho$ is a density function on $\Omega$ and $p_1,\ldots, p_n\in (0,1)$ are given weights satisfying

$$\int_{\Omega}\rho(z)dz ~=~ 1 ~=~ \sum_{k=1}^n p_k.$$

According to Iosif Pinelis, to show $\inf_{x\in\Omega^n}\sup_{y\in\mathbb R^n}F(x,y)=\sup_{y\in\mathbb R^n}\inf_{x\in\Omega^n}F(x,y)$, it suffices to show, for each $y\in\mathbb R^n$, there exists a unique $x_y\in\Omega^n$ s.t. $\inf_{x\in\Omega^n}F(x,y)=F(x_y,y)$.

It is known that $(V_k)_{1\le k\le n}$ is the weighted Voronoi tessellation (if $y=(0,\ldots, 0)$ it becomes the Voronoi tessellation, and the unique minimizer is given by the centroidal Voronoi tessellation).

Comment: Can you give details/references on "the unique minimizer is given by the centroidal Voronoi tessellation"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Actually this is what I wish to know. I've just learnt this aspect recently (as it's related to my current research), and as I saw your answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337261/semi-discrete-wasserstein-distance-to-uniform So I suppose you know better than I...

Comment: The only reference that I have now is http://alice.loria.fr/publications/papers/2009/onCVT/onCVT.pdf Now I don't know any result concerning the uniqueness of minimizer, but I will let you know as soon as I find any related reference

Comment: I'll try to think about the uniqueness. Actually, some weaker versions of the uniqueness would be enough, as is now detailed a bit in my answer.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you very much for the consideration. If you don't mind I can email you my draft which might clarify the motivation.

Comment: Sure, it may be helpful to know the motivation.

Answer (score 1):

It's false. Take $M = [0,1]$ and $N = \mathbb{R}$ and define $F(x,y) = 1 - |x-y|$. Taking $y_x = x$ satisfies condition (2). Here $\inf_M \sup_N F(x,y) = 1$ and $\sup_N \inf_M F(x,y) = 1/2$, achieved when $y = 1/2$.

Edit: this answers the original question. The new version of the question, with $N$ compact, is falsified by taking $N=[0,1]$ in the above example.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could the two operator be exchanged if $N$ is also assumed to be compact (see what I've edited)?

Comment: Just take $N = [0,1]$ in my example.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Nik Weaver, the minimax duality will not hold in general without assuming that $F(x,y)$ is convex in $x$.

However, if, for instance, for each $y$ the minimum of $F(x,y)$ in $x$ is attained at only one point, then under natural regularity conditions we have the minimax duality. See e.g. [Theorem 1.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=8-ZbWFeSS0UC&pg=PA315&lpg=PA315&dq=minimax%20pinelis&source=bl&ots=Jti5DyWe7f&sig=ACfU3U33w24EahOvQ3fxBu_Ix8JkZEApWA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG583vgZjkAhUKi6wKHVtjD-UQ6AEwB3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=minimax%20pinelis&f=false) or [Theorem 1](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1135010) or [Theorem 1](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1135069).

*Remark 1:* In Nik Weaver's counterexample, with $M=N=[0,1]$, the condition that the minimum of $F(x,y)$ in $x$ be attained at only one point was violated only for one value of $y$, namely $y=1/2$, and that was enough to bring the minimax duality down! On the other hand, as seen from the above citations, it is not necessary to require a unique minimizer in $x$ for each $y$ -- it is enough to require it just for one special $y$. In Nik Weaver's counterexample, $1/2$ would be precisely that special $y$ -- for which the uniqueness condition fails, though.

*Remark 2:* A necessary and sufficient condition for the minimax duality for generalized concave-convex functions $F$ is given [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01158303). This condition consists in the upper semi-continuity at $0$ of a certain functional constructed based on $F$.

Comment: Thank you very kindly for the detailed comments (I did not know about Thereom 1.1 or Theorem 1 before). I have now added more details about function $F$ in PS2 (see above). After taking a look at your previous answers, I believe that you are familiar with optimal transport and Voronoi tessellation. Now to check the condition ensuring the minmax duality, it suffices to check the uniqueness of $argmin_{x\in M}F(x,y)$. For the function $F$ defined above, do you have any idea whether this condition is satisfied? Thanks a lot!