# Reference request on computational schemes for $\inf_{x\in\Omega^n}\sup_{y\in\mathbb R^n}F(x,y)$

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$ be compact, $\rho$ be a density function on $\Omega$ and $p_1,\ldots, p_n\in (0,1)$ be weights satisfying $\int_{\Omega}\rho(z)dz=1=\sum_{k=1}^n p_k$. We consider the optimization problem $\inf_{x\in\Omega^n}\sup_{y\in\mathbb R^n}F(x,y)$, where $F$ is defined by

$$F(x,y)~:=~\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{V_k(x,y)}\left\{|z-x_k|^2-y_k\right\}\rho(z)dx+\sum_{k=1}^n p_ky_k,$$

with $x:=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)\in\Omega^n$, $y:=(y_1,\ldots, y_n)\in\mathbb R^n$ and

$$V_k(x,y)~:=~\big\{z\in\Omega:~ |z-x_k|^2-y_k\le |z-x_{i}|^2-y_{i},~ \forall 1\le i\le n\big\}.$$

My question is whether there exists any known computational scheme for solving numerically $\inf_{x\in\Omega^n}\sup_{y\in\mathbb R^n}F(x,y)$?

Some thoughts: This question appears in [Reference request on Min-Max theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338979/reference-request-on-min-max-theorem) where I asked $\inf_{x\in\Omega^n}\sup_{y\in\mathbb R^n}F(x,y)=\sup_{y\in\mathbb R^n}\inf_{x\in\Omega^n}F(x,y)$. To the best of my knowledge (*under suitable conditions*):

(1) the first order partial derivatives $\partial_x F$ and $\partial_y F$ have explicit expression;

(2) the second order partial derivatives $\partial_{xx} F$ and $\partial_{yy} F$ have explicit expression;

(3) For fixed $x\in\Omega^n$, $\sup_{y\in\mathbb R^n}F(x,y)$ can be numerically computed (related to optimal transport);

(4) For fixed $y\in\mathbb R^n$, $\inf_{x\in\Omega^n}F(x,y)$ can be numerically computed (related to Lloyd's algorithm).

Any comments or references are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood correctly that the function is smooth in $x$ and $y$ you can use Nemirovski's *Mirror Prox* from this paper

Nemirovski, Arkadi. "Prox-method with rate of convergence O (1/t) for variational inequalities with Lipschitz continuous monotone operators and smooth convex-concave saddle point problems." SIAM Journal on Optimization 15.1 (2004): 229-251.

which achieves the provably optimal convergence rate for this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Yes, $\nabla_x F$, $\nabla^2_{xx} F$, $\nabla_y F$ and $\nabla^2_{yy} F$ can be explicitly calculated (not sure for $\nabla^2_{xy} F$ at this stage but I believe it is also explicit).

Comment: Oh, I just realized that I forgot to make sure that your function is concave in $y$ and convex in $x$. I just assumed so because you posted under the tag "convex optimization"... Can you confirm that this is indeed the case?

Comment: The concavity of $y\mapsto F(x,y)$ follows by definition. However, $x\mapsto F(x,y)$ is not always convex. For example, taking $n=d=2$, $\Omega=[0,1]\times [0,1]$, $\rho(z)=\mathbf{1}_{\Omega}(z)$ and $y_1=y_2=0$, one may find $x\mapsto F(x,0)$ is not convex.

Comment: in this case my answer is useless and you should probably remove the convex optimization tag

Answer (score 0):

This problem is called semi-discrete optimal transportation, you can find an algorithm in, e.g.,

- Quentin Mérigot, [A multiscale approach to optimal transport](http://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-8659.2011.02032.x), Computer Graphics Forum, Volume 30, Issue 5, August 2011 [[hal-00604684](https://hal.science/hal-00604684)]